# Sound doesn't play whem receiving push notifications in Ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

To initialize push notifications in my Ionic app for iOS and Android, I added following code:

```js
    const options: PushOptions = {
       android: {
       alert: 'true',
       badge: true,
       sound: 'true'
       },
       ios: {
           alert: 'true',
           badge: true,
           sound: 'true'
       },
       windows: {},
       browser: {
           pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
       }
    };

    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);
```

Comment: This was due to error in phonegap push plugin.